# Recycler view edit text focus on activity starting

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `RecyclerView` with items that have a bunch of `EditText`-s on it. Now when I start the activity one of the EditText get focused on and the keyboard starts showing. How to fix this issue so that the EditText is not focused when Activity is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the manifest file for your activity add this:
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

Comment: Worked! Also added `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to the parent LinearLayout so that the cursor doesn't show.

Answer (score 1):

In your row xml of `RecyclerView`, remove requestfocus tag from `EditText`.